# How to pass value to component which I get from another by onClick event

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie in react. So sorry)
I created my icon component which has svg icons inside:

```
<IconPick icon={'globe'} />
```

then I created array of icons' names:

```
iconsList = ['globe', 'mail', ...];
```

And map through this component to show all icons that I have in one block:

```
<ul className="icons-list__wrapper">
    {iconsList.map(icon =>
        <li data-icon={icon} key={icon}>
            <IconPick icon={icon} />
        </li>
    )}
</ul>
```

Everything is working fine. Now I want to make from this block kind of Icon Picker.
So when person click on any icon it will be appeared in a new block, so I used onClick:

```
    handleCheck = (e) => {
        e.currentTarget.dataset.icon
    }
...
    <div>
        <ul className="icons-list__wrapper">
            {iconsList.map(icon =>
                <li
                data-icon={icon}
                key={icon}
                onClick={this.handleCheck}
                >
                    <IconPick icon={icon} />
                </li>
            )}
        </ul>
    </div>
...
```

So now I create a new div in which I want to pass data value that I get onClick into clickedIcon:

```
<div>
    <IconPick icon={clickedIcon}/>
</div>
```

But I can't do it right, can you help me? Or just advice.

I will be very grateful.

Comment: Check React documentation and read about the `state` and `synthetic events`

Comment: Thanks. I read about it and know how change with state simple text, but can't take value from clicked icon and send it to new block, for me it's too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the clickedIcon as state of the component.

```
state={
   clickedIcon:undefined // initially it is undefined
}
```

In your handler you update the clickedIcon value :

```
handleCheck = icon => this.setState({clickedIcon : icon});
```

Pass the icon clicked value :

```
<li
     data-icon={icon}
     key={icon}
     onClick={()=>this.handleCheck(icon)}>
   <IconPick icon={icon} />
</li>
```

And finally you can pass the clickedIcon value to your IconPick easily :

```
<div>
    <IconPick icon={this.state.clickedIcon}/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of React is that it lets you handle your data in a meta `state` on your Components instead of making you insert the same data as `data-attributes` to be later collected by your 'handling code'.

Try using:

```
class IconPicker extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      iconList: [ '...'],
      selectedIcon: ''
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="icons-list__wrapper">
          {this.state.iconsList.map(icon =>
            <li
              key={icon}
              onClick={() => this.setState({...this.state, selectedIcon: icon})}
            >
              <IconPick icon={icon} />
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
        <div>
          <IconPick icon={this.state.selectedIcon}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Japsz. This way is more practical.